# What javascript libraries or game engines to build 3D room with x, y, z co-ordinates for tracking moving objects?

Tags: javascript, three.js, coordinates, rfid

I'm building a simple demonstrator web application that will display upto 5 individual objects being tracked in real-time within a pre-defined room. I've been looking at three.js so far, but is there anything simpler, or any examples similar to my case scenario?

For example, if my room's dimensions were 5m width, 10m length, 3m height, I would like to use a javascript library to display this and within the boundaries, update the frontend using ajax requests (or socket.io streaming data) to show the movement of upto 5 active RFID devices. The data being retrieved from the database has the following data structure:

```
    {
      tag_id: 'test_tag',
      time: '2017-06-13 14:00:00',
      x_coord: 3,
      y_coord: 5,
      z_coord: 10
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question is very difficult, based on your knowledge and requirements. [Here is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WebGL_frameworks) a list of most of the JS WebGL frameworks. They differ extensively, by complexity and purpose.

The only way for you, is to read about them, and make your selection.